# on load function when subscription ready on Meteor Blaze?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using Meteor and blaze for my project and I would like to call a JavaScript function in a Meteor template. More precisely, i used of course publisher subscriber but when i subscribe in order to retrieve information from the mongo DB, i would like a function to be triggered.

As a matter of fact, i retrieve the data but it deals with row data like "true" or "false" and i would like to call a function that affect different properties according to the result of the data.

For example, if the element of my db is set to "true", when the subscription will be ready (or as soon as my page is loaded) it will replace the "true" with a green rectangle.

To do so, i was wondering if we can use

```
Template.devicesConfiguration.onCreated(function(){
var self = this;
self.autorun(function(){
    self.subscribe('Buttons');

    //call a javascript function that uses the result of the db

    });
});
```

or in

```
Template.devicesConfiguration.helpers({
    buttons:()=>{   

        //call a javascript function that uses the result of the db

        return ButtonsCollection.find({}); 

    }

});
```

or even a method ?

does someone have an idea ? thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a Subscribe followed by simple helper functions :

```
Template.devicesConfiguration.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('Buttons'); // Subscribe to your buttons
});

Template.devicesConfiguration.helpers({
    // Will return a "transformed" array of all the Buttons in collection
    buttons(){
        return ButtonsCollection.find({}) // Find all buttons
                                .map(button => {
                                    // Do something with button object
                                    // Like check true / false and change rectangle color
                                })
    }
});
```

I simply subscribe to the data on template creation.

Then I register a `buttons`helper that returns data from the collection, but execute a transformation (the map function) on the data before returning it.

You could then use `{{#each button in buttons}}` in your template to loop through the data and display each button.

Comment: I tried to do so but errors, i guess the syntax isn't correct but i understand the idea. 
Here the code of the template helpers :

`buttons:()=>{ 
   return ButtonsCollection.find({}).map(button=>{

 var buttonValue = ButtonsCollection.find({},{fields:{value:"true"}}).fetch();
     
 var CheckButtonsLed = document.getElementsByClassName("CheckButtonsLed");
     
  for(i=0;i<buttonValue.length;i++){
      CheckButtonsLed[i].style.backgroundColor="green";
  }
  
}); 
}`

Then i used {{#each button in buttons}}.

(My Button Collection has 2 attributes : name, and value)

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.devicesConfiguration.helpers({
    buttons() {
        return ButtonsCollection.find({}).map(button => {
            if(button.value === true) button.className = 'green';
            else button.className = 'red'; 
        })
    }
});
```

in template something like:

```
{{#each button in buttons}}
    <button class={button.className}>{button.name}</button>
{{/each}}
```

haven't written any Blaze in some time but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand the idea :) i tried to implement it. It works but the handlebars do not display my buttons' properties wether i used `{{button name}}`, `{{button.name}}`, `{{name}}`, `{button name}`, `{button.name}`, or `{name}`. However, the helpers part works, i could for instance `console.log(button.name + button.value)` according to its value statement in the if loop.